# Image Source Binding not display anything

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've an image structured in this way:

```
<Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHomeShield}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

and a label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MatchController.Match.TeamHomeShield}" />
```

my problem's that I can't get the image displayed on the Image, but on the label I can see the value of `TeamHomeShield`, the property is created in this way:

```
        private string _teamHomeShield;
        public string TeamHomeShield
        {
            get { return _teamHomeShield; }
            set
            {
                _teamHomeShield = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _teamAwayShield;
        public string TeamAwayShield
        {
            get { return _teamAwayShield; }
            set
            {
                _teamAwayShield = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

why happen this?

Comment: Works for me with `TeamHomeShield = "http://cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/1270.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Image source format
"/YourAssemblyName;component/YourPath/YourImage with extension"

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="200" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = objviewmodel;
        objviewmodel.ImagePath = @"/ImageLoading;component/Assets/Desert.jpg"; // your image path

    }
    viewmodel objviewmodel = new viewmodel();

}


public class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnpropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    private string _ImagePath=string.Empty;

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _ImagePath; }
        set { _ImagePath = value; OnpropertyChanged(); }
    }

}
```

Comment: the image is taken from internet isn't a binding problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ImageSource** property (not string) for binding images correctly.

For example:

```
public ImageSource ImagePath { get; set; }
```

Comment: the compiler underline ImageSource, seems that isn't recognized why?

Comment: @Vandehusend System.Windows.Media.ImageSource